# Simplifying $\sin^{-1}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}$

Tags: trigonometry

I was wondering how you would simplify this inverse trig function.

$$\sin^{-1}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}$$

Is there a way to do it without using a calculator? or is calculator the best approach.

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [mathjax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing to simplify. You just need to know the fact that $$\sin{\frac{\pi}{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Therefore $$\sin^{-1}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}=\frac{\pi}{3}$$

The answer is unique because, as you might remember, there is only one value on the interval $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ (the range of the inverse sine function) where $\sin{x}$ equals $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and that, of course, is $\frac{\pi}{3}$.